# Automatic photo to OCR to Sheets - dumb meter to smart meter for £/$20 :)

Tags: ftp, video-streaming, ip-camera

I am working out how to get a Tapo TC60 camera to upload a still of the feed on a timer to an FTP server.

Once I work that out, I will use a free OCR to read the image ( a gas meter ) into a spreadsheet so I can track usage.

The problem I am having is getting the Tapo camera I have to take the image.

So I need a solution to taking a still of the camera feed and uploading it to an API callable URL.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One solution:

1. Install an RTSP accepting software like VLC, ManyCam or Instacam
2. Set up to take a still of feed
3. Sync local folder to remote folder using an FTP sync software
4. continue with Free OCR or similar

I am going to try this.